# How to produce webpack bundle to be consumed by another webpack?

Tags: webpack

Suppose that I have a script "hot.js" that I want to build using [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack):

```js
console.log(import.meta.webpackHot);
```

This is simply printing the value of `import.meta.webpackHot`.

The idea is that this script would be bundled and then added to another webpack by prepending it to the entry, i.e. My another `webpack` project would consume it as:

```js
entry: [
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/hot.js'),
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/app.ts'),
],
```

The problem is, that `dist/hot.js` currently looks as follows:

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    // The require scope
/******/    var __webpack_require__ = {};
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define __esModule on exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/            if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/            }
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/*!**************************!*\
  !*** ./client/client.ts ***!
  \**************************/
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
console.log(/* unsupported import.meta.webpackHot */ undefined);


/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=client.js.map
```

The key thing to notice is that `import.meta.webpackHot` was replaced in this bundle with `/* unsupported import.meta.webpackHot */`, whereas I would expect that `import.meta.webpackHot` would refer to the import available in the second webpack bundle which includes `HotModuleReplacementPlugin`.

So how do I produce a webpack bundle that would work when imported in another webpack bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if this is the correct answer, but my particular use case is resolved using `DefinePlugin`:

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'import.meta.webpackHot': 'import.meta.webpackHot',
}),
```

This produces `webpack` bundle that leaves `import.meta.webpackHot` untouched, which is enough for it to work in the context of the second bundle:

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    // The require scope
/******/    var __webpack_require__ = {};
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define __esModule on exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/            if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/            }
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/*!**************************!*\
  !*** ./client/client.ts ***!
  \**************************/
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
console.log(import.meta.webpackHot);


/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=client.js.map
```